# Center cursor on focus in div contentEditable (centered horizontally and vertically)

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, contenteditable

I have table with many `textarea`'s (already changed to `div`'s with attribute `contentEditable`), also with CSS I done that the `innerHTML` is centered horizontally and also vertically. Everything is working fine, just one thing is not OK - when you enter `div`, so its focused, the cursor is in the left top corner, but when you start writting its moved to the center.

How can I do, that when you focus the `div`, the cursor will be right in the center?

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/7v4tnz2g/)

Thanks a lot.

**EDITED:**
Sorry, my fault, its not working only in Firefox.

Comment: I checked your demo and it's working just like you wanted it to. Are you using IE?

Comment: You forgot to mention important information: in which browser do you see the behavior you have described? Because I have tested it in Chrome and it works fine: if I click anywhere in a table cell, cursor is in center of the cell.

Comment: the problem just happens in the so-called ***FireFox***. So I don't think you need to fix that tiny bug which will just bother FireFox's users (which are also limited in quantity).

Comment: Yes, thats true, but most mine users are using this table in Firefox :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FF you need to reset your div to an inline-box and regulr vertical-align so it stands in the middle of the cell: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7v4tnz2g/1/)**

```
.termin:focus{/* only once focused, else nothing to click on if empty */
    height: auto;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

You need to fix your valign to td too : vertical-align:center; does not exist :)

```
.terminy td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;/* fixed with a valid value*/
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: demo is working, but on my website, when you focus it, the cursor is about 10px to the bottom from the middle :-/

Comment: @Legionar did you reset vertical-align too and fixed your CSS for td ?

Comment: Yes, both, and there is no other CSS that could break it

Comment: `height: auto;` this is the same on my website, like it will be `height: 0px;` - the same result, about 10px down from the center. So I changed it to `height: 20px;` and now its right in the center. Dont know, why its not working with `auto`, and in jsfiddle its working...

Comment: probably from  a reset somewhere else :)

Comment: no no, I removed all other CSS, just leave the same as in jsfiddle; but doesnt matter, its working now, thanks :)