# How to place cursor position at the start of center aligned placeholder of contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, placeholder

I have the following piece of code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="title" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Title"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.title {
   width: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
   content: attr(placeholder);

}
```

It results in a center-aligned editable div with a placeholder. My problem is that when the element is first focused the cursor is positioned at the start of the div, as opposed to where the placeholder is: !http://screencast.com/t/66HWb3wKiV

I want the placeholder to remain visible until a character is actually typed, with the cursor positioned at the start of the placeholder. How would I be able to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304708/center-cursor-on-focus-in-div-contenteditable-centered-horizontally-and-vertica

Comment: @Burn Unfortunately that code doesn't apply to placeholders. The problem that I have is that it's not until a key is typed (or some text is already there) that the cursor is centered. My problem is having it be centered before that, when it is first focused, with a placeholder shown.

Comment: Long time, but I posted an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288975/centering-the-placeholder-caret-in-contenteditable-element — you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this Issue.

change your css:

```
.title {
   width: 500px;
   margin: 0 25%;
}
```