# Centering the placeholder caret in contentEditable element

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/mb76koj3/.

```css
[contentEditable=true]:empty::before{
  content:attr(data-ph);
  color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true" data-ph="Name"></h1>
```

The problem is the `<h1>` is centered, but the placeholder caret isn't centered (until you start typing). The caret is on the left side, how can I change this?

Comment: Interestingly, in IE11 the cursor starts at the end of the content, Chrome and Firefox render it left-aligned.  Chrome also shows a blue border where the other two do not.

Answer (score 10):

Not an ideal solution but we can fake the effect by applying a `padding-left` of `50%` to the `:empty` element to make the cursor appear at the middle.

And then align the placeholder (the pseudo-element) at the middle by using absolute positioning and a negative value of `translateX` transform function.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() { /* CSS Hack to fix the position of cursor on FF */
  [contentEditable=true]:empty {
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: .25em;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  }
}

[contentEditable=true]:empty {
  padding-left: 50%;
  text-align: left; /* Fix the issue on IE */
}

[contentEditable=true]:empty::before{
  content:attr(data-ph);
  color: #CCC;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform:  translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform:  translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform:  translateX(-50%);
  transform:  translateX(-50%);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true" data-ph="Name"></h1>
```

The only problem that remains — as can be seen in the OP's provided code — is that on Firefox, an empty `<br>` element is appended to `contentEditable` elements which causes `:empty` pseudo-class not matching the element anymore. Hence the placeholder won't be restored.

However since the question is about the position of the cursor, I assume this behavior is just fine for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at [Hashem Qolami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29289115/1913729), I came up with this:

```css
[contentEditable=true]:empty {
    padding-left: 50%;
}

[contentEditable=true]:empty::before{
    content:attr(data-ph);
    color: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -100%;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true" data-ph="Name"></h1>
```

However, [adamdc78](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3207850/adamdc78) discovered 2 problems:

- In IE11, the cursor appears after the placeholder.
- In Firefox, the placeholder is not restored after typing and emptying.

At this time, I can't figure out how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been reported in 2020, but still not fixed. You can vote at : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1625298